# opening a word document using flex or actionscript in Flex 4 appliaction

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Need a solution to  open  a  word as attachment as inline in a data grid and my  doc  is saved in  my  database  and  after retrieving it i  need to show them as  attachment in one of  the column and on  click of the  attachment document needs  to  open  inline or  in new  tab

please need  quick  solutions thanks a  lot in  advance

Comment: You'll have to write your own code to parse the word doc format and display it in Flex.  I expect that approach to be extremely time consuming.  I would recommend giving the user a link to open the word document.  Pop it open with navigateToURL() and the browser will deal with it.

Comment: I  tried  using  var u:URLRequest = new URLRequest("assets/contractMngment/Sample.doc");
    navigateToURL(u,"_blank"); its  opens a  pop with  option  open  ,save and save as when i clicked on  open  it  keeps on  downloading and never return the contol  nor opened the  doc is specified

Comment: That relates to the settings of your browser and computer.